# 'UnityEnvironment' object has no attribute 'behavior_spec'

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

I followed this [link to doc](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Executable.md) to create environment of my own.

But when i run this

```
from mlagents_envs.environment import UnityEnvironment
env = UnityEnvironment(file_name="v1-ball-cube-game.x86_64")


env.reset()
behavior_names = env.behavior_spec.keys()
print(behavior_names)
```

Game window pop up and then terminal show error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 6, in <module>
    behavior_names = env.behavior_spec.keys()
AttributeError: 'UnityEnvironment' object has no attribute 'behavior_spec'
```

despite the fact that this is the exact snippet as shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Python-API.md#loading-a-unity-environment).

I created environment by following [this](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Create-New.md) (it make without brain) and i was able to train the model by .conf file. Now i wanted to connect to python API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use stable documents and stable repo( ***RELEASE_TAGS*** ) to achieve stable results. Unity ML Agents changes it's syntax every few months so that is problem if you are following master branch.

```
env.get_behavior_spec(behavior_name: str)
```

Should solve your problem.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/release_2/docs/Python-API.md

Comment: `behavior_name: str` is giving some syntax error. Do i need to replace it with something ? Like i trained with .yaml file with `behaviors:
    RollerBall:`