# 'UnityEnvironment' object has no attribute 'get_agent_groups' ( mlagents_envs 0.16.1 )

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

python version as

```
Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

And was able to follow [this](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/release-0.15.0/docs/Learning-Environment-Create-New.md) docs successfully 

But then i want to control environment with PYTHON-API so i followed [this](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/release-0.15.0/docs/Python-API.md) and with my code

```
from mlagents_envs.environment import UnityEnvironment
import mlagents_envs
env = UnityEnvironment(file_name="v1-ball-cube-game.x86_64", 
                       base_port=5004, 
                       seed=1, 
                       side_channels=[])
# env = UnityEnvironment(file_name=None, base_port=5004, seed=1,worker_id=0, side_channels=[])

print(mlagents_envs.__version__)  # outputs 0.16.1
print(env.reset()) # outputs None
print(env) # outputs <mlagents_envs.environment.UnityEnvironment object at 0x7f3ed001c278>
print(str(env.get_agent_groups())) # outputs error
```

Out put of above code

```
0.16.1
None
<mlagents_envs.environment.UnityEnvironment object at 0x7f3ed001c278>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(str(env.get_agent_groups()))
AttributeError: 'UnityEnvironment' object has no attribute 'get_agent_groups'
```

I do have this code and **why is function `get_agent_groups`** not defined ? I am unable to find the solution. Plus it is written in docs

Comment: Very probably related to or a duplicate of your other question ['UnityEnvironment' object has no attribute 'behavior_spec'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194104/unityenvironment-object-has-no-attribute-behavior-spec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like 'derHugo' already mentioned it is basically a duplicate.

You're pointing to the documentation of version 0.15 but using version 0.16.1

`env.get_agent_groups()` was replaced by `env.get_behavior_names()`

[This](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/release_2_docs/docs/Python-API.md) is the documentation that matches your version

Comment: you're welcome, glad I could help. My ML-Agents playlist might be interesting for you.
[link](https://youtube.com/BotAcademyYT)

Comment: Subscribed.. Will watch them soon